# count up timer in javascript, keep the time when refresh

Tags: javascript

A plain timer formats like "mm:ss".
**But**, this timer should keep the time after refresh. I tried `sessionStorage`, but it doesn't work straight.
Right now, I send the time back to server every time before the page refresh and get the time from server when start loading the page.
Any other better ideas without server involved?

Comment: Ok can you show us code here?

Comment: Could store the start time in a cookie or something and use a bit of maths to see how long has elapsed since then.

Comment: sessionStorage should work fine, post your busted code.

Comment: I don't have a even busted code yet. In order to implement pause function in the future, I think it can only use a 'totaltime' variable and increase it by 1 per second. The problem is when to set and get this variable in sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage should work fine, just remember the value stored must be a string.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('ts', Date.now().toString());
```

Here's a quick sample fiddle to demonstrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/9cv2mqoh/

Comment: This code will generally do the trick, but the way you use setInterval makes it impossible to implement pause function. It would be better if you can use a 'totaltime' variable and increase it by 1 per second.